wind speed and force over a saw tooth roof
I have a saw tooth roof covering 45,000m2, each saw tooth has a drop of 4 metres between each and each saw tooth is 12m wide. if i have 140km wind can you please tell me the wind force over the saw tooth.

are the teeth symmetrical? is the wind direction inline or across the teeth? what have you researched so far?
